# c#: how to know the full path of dll used in DllImport?

Tags: c#

I've import dll in my code like that:

```
[DllImport("dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern int function(String pars, StringBuilder err);
```

I was wondered that function works, but it is not inside project and not inside Debug or Release folders. I.e. "dll.dll" should not be availabe because it is not in the current project folder, however it IS available. Now I want to know the exact full path of the dll used at runtime, but don't know how to get it.

Comment: This may be useful: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I think the same holds true with P/Invoke. However it doesn't say how to determine the filename of a loaded dll ;-)

Comment: @pst: You should post that as an answer because... it is the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going to have to use the win32 API.

First use [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing "dll.dll" to it. Then pass that handle to [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
string GetDllPath()
{
      const int MAX_PATH = 260;
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
      IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle("dll.dll");  // might return IntPtr.Zero until 
                                                    // you call a method in  
                                                    // dll.dll causing it to be 
                                                    // loaded by LoadLibrary

      Debug.Assert(hModule != IntPtr.Zero);
      uint size = GetModuleFileName(hModule, builder, builder.Capacity);
      Debug.Assert(size > 0);
      return builder.ToString();   // might need to truncate nulls
}

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    [PreserveSig]
    public static extern uint GetModuleFileName
    (
        [In] IntPtr hModule,        
        [Out] StringBuilder lpFilename,        
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int nSize
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- this should hold true with P/Invoke, but the behavior is slightly alterable depending upon load method. However it doesn't say how to determine the filename of a loaded DLL ;-)

---

A completely un-tested and perhaps ill-advised solution *to find the DLL path at run-time*. This assumes that P/Invoke and LoadLibrary use the same resolution (e.g. P/Invoke doesn't use LoadLibraryEx with LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) and that there are no awful conflicts with this approach.

1. Load the DLL with [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LoadLibaryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Find the filename of the module using [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the handle obtained in step #1.
3. Unload the module with [FreeLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). P/Invoke should keep the module reference-count > 0, but again, this is untested ;-)

(There is no guarantee about the correctness or validity of the above solution. Suggestions, warnings and/or corrections welcome. YMMV.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to find out, use [dependency-walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)

It can even 'monitor' your application in runtime and detect dynamic loads so nothing remains hidden